# Repeat a javascript function with a delay in it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript function that cycles through background images inside of a div. It works well, but it stops when it runs through all the images. How can I call this again when it's done?

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        FlipBackgroundOver();
    });

function FlipBackgroundOver() 
    { 

        $(".bkgrndimg").each(function(index) {
            $(this).hide();
            $(this).delay(5000 * index).fadeIn(5000).fadeOut();
        });

    }
```

If I add FlipBackgroundOver(); inside the function, it goes into an infinite loop because the delay doesn't stop the function execution.

Here is a fiddle with what I'm working with: http://jsfiddle.net/RyGKV/

Comment: Err, `setTimeout`?

Comment: Are you really using jq1.5.2? Otherwise, use `promise()`: http://jsfiddle.net/RyGKV/813/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On jq 1.6+, you should use `promise()` relevant callback:

```
function test() {
    $("img").each(function(index) {
        $(this).delay(3000 * index).fadeIn(3000).fadeOut();
    }).promise().done(test);
}
```

### -jsFiddle-

Answer (score 0):

You can use setInterval to repeat execution with a dealy

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(FlipBackgroundOver, 10000); // delay should be based on the number of images => numer_of_images * delay_for_each
});
```

You can change the delay to value you want based on the number of images you have.

Comment: what happens if one cycle takes more than 10 seconds? We don't know how many images there will be

Comment: @ADyson delay should be based on the number of images. I have mentioned in the answer.

Comment: You still have no guarantee than the next interval callback is called **after** last animation has completed

Comment: @ArunGhosh and the number of images could be dynamic, determined by what is uploaded on the server, or some other factor - we don't know. So it's not a good idea to hard-code this.

Answer (score 0):

Create a loop in an infinite interval by your own. I used the helper function `next` for this.

```
var elements = $("img");
var index = 0;

function next() {
    index = ++index == elements.length ? 0 : index;
    elements.hide().eq(index).fadeIn(3000).fadeOut();
}

function start() {
    // show first one directly
    next();

    // start infinite loop
    setInterval(function() {
         next();
    }, 3000);
}

start();
```

[Working example.](http://jsfiddle.net/RyGKV/814/)